# Android fragment throws NPE when I get a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am building an android app with fragment in it. I declared my recyclerview in global variable scope and call `findViewById()` in Fragment's `OnCreateView()` method. Here is my fragment class:

```
public class AdoptedPetFragment extends Fragment implements OnRemoveButtonClickListener{
    private AdoptedPetAdapter aPetAdapter;
    private RecyclerView aPetRecyclerView;
    private ArrayList<Integer> adoptedPetIds;

    public AdoptedPetFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_adopted_pet, container, false);
        this.adoptedPetIds = FileHandler.getAdoptedPetIdList();
        this.aPetAdapter = new AdoptedPetAdapter(adoptedPetIds);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        aPetRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.adoptedRecView);
        aPetRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        aPetRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        aPetRecyclerView.setAdapter(aPetAdapter);
        aPetAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return v;
    }
    ...
    //I have a listener to catch a button click event, it works like a charm,
    //I get the petItem as expected.
    @Override
    public void onRemoveButtonClick(Pet petItem) {
        FileHandler.removeAdoptedPet(petItem.getPetId());
        adoptedPetIds = FileHandler.getAdoptedPetIdList(); //It reload the list.

        //Here is the error, it throws NPE.
        aPetRecyclerView.invalidate();
        ....
    }
```

I tried to call `aPetAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` too in that `onRemoveButtonClick()` method, but it throws the same NPE.
Here is the error stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.invalidate()' on a null object reference
        at com.evangunawan.adoptme.Home.AdoptedPetFragment.onRemoveButtonClick(AdoptedPetFragment.java:69)
        at com.evangunawan.adoptme.Controller.AdoptedPetAdapter.lambda$onBindViewHolder$0$AdoptedPetAdapter(AdoptedPetAdapter.java:63)
        ...
```

Is there anything that I missed? I knew that I declared the objects in global variable and I assigned the object in `oncreateview()`, so I think it should not be any problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sometimes views are not properly initialized inside `onCreateView` method. You should always initialize your views inside `onViewCreated`. Just move everything inside that method.

Comment: How you are getting callback from adapter without passing OnRemoveButtonClickListener reference

Comment: @AramSheroyan It still not working, i still get NPE from it :(.

Comment: @KishanMaurya shoot, I realized something from it,
`OnRemoveButtonClickListener mListener = new AdoptedPetFragment();` from the adapter class is the culprit i guess, lol. Thank you :)